# Nextjs translation from api no locale in path

Tags: next.js, internationalization

I am new in NextJs and trying to migrate an actual React app to a NextJs app

I have three locales on my website `en`, `fr`, `es`, the landing page path is different depending on the user locale `/home`, `/accueil`, `/inicio`

First, I tried to manage my locales with `next-i18next` I had a little issue as you can't get translations from api, I had to download them on build but the bigger issue was that I had to have the locale in the url `/en/home`, `/fr/accueil`, `/es/inicio` and I do not want that.

So then I tried to move to `react-i18next`

my `i18n.js` file

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(Backend)
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: `...`,
        },
        react: {
            useSuspense: false
        },
        supportedLngs: ['en', 'fr', 'es'],
        fallbackLng: ['en'],
        detection: {
            order: ['cookie', 'navigator'],
            lookupCookie: 'i18nextLng',
            caches: ['cookie'],
            cookieOptions: { path: '/', sameSite: 'strict' },
            checkWhitelist: true
        }
    })

export default i18n
```

And then I am including it in my `_app.js`

```
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import '../i18n';
import '../styles/globals.scss'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp;
```

But I have the following warning `Text content did not match. Server: "Brand" Client: "brand.name"`

Should be because i18n is loading the translation on client side and not on server side

The translations should be loaded from `getStaticProps` but I do not know if I can adapt `react-i18next` to do so or use a lower level of `i18n`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the i18n feature of Next.js you need to have the language in the url: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

To directly use react-i18next, you may have a look at: https://react.i18next.com/latest/ssr

btw: there is currently a pending PR for next-i18next that will enable client side translation loading: https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/pull/1726
(https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/tree/master/example/next)

Comment: Thanks but to change locale I change to call `router.push` as `i18n.changeLanguage` and it will add the locale in the url. I also tried setting NEXT_LOCALE same issue if add the locale in the url from `/`